# analytic continuation related to Chebyshev functions

Tags: nt.number-theory, cv.complex-variables

Let $\psi$ be the Chebyshev function. I would like to prove that the function
$\sum_{n\ge0}(\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}e^{\psi(k)})w^n$ can be analyticaly continued on an open set of $\mathbb C$ containing $\mathbb R^-$.

Does anyone know a way to prove that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the Chebyshev function?

Comment: This the function defined from the Von Mangoldt function:$$\Psi(x)=\sum_{p\text{ prime}}\left[\log_p(x)\right]\log(p)$$

Comment: Yes this entire function is defined on the disk with radius $1/3$. But I would like to know whether it can be analytically expanded to an open se of $\mathbb C$ containing $\mathbb R^-$.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read properly.